# Group Swtich Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Listview that is creating dynamically data and a switch in every row, what i want is when i toggle a switch the others untoggle.
Is this possible to do?

Example:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding article_description}"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="13"  Margin="10,5,0,-6" Grid.Row="0" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding dish_name}" 
                               FontSize="13" Margin="10,0,0,2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="LabelReserved"  Text="{Binding reserved}" IsVisible="false" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/> 
                        <Switch Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" IsEnabled="False" Toggled="SwitchMenu_OnToggled" >
                            <Switch.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Switch" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference LabelReserved},
                               Path=Text.Length}" Value="7">
                                    <Setter Property="IsToggled" Value="true" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Switch.Triggers>
                        </Switch>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Why dont you bind your switch to a `IsToggled` property on the item viewmodel and then in your Switch Toggled event untoggle all but your own

Comment: @user1 I dont understand what you want me to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Note:*** This solution was a bit of an experiment on my part - so I would recommend that, if you decide to implement this, use it with caution.

The intent here is to extend `Switch` to be able to act as a grouped radio button.

First step would be to create a `IsToggled` or `IsChecked` or similar property in the item that acts as `BindingContext` to each list-item. You can implement an interface like:

```
public interface IToggableItem 
{ 
    string GroupName { get; } //not mandatory, only added to support grouped lists
    bool IsChecked { get; set; } 
}
```

Second step would be extend `Switch` to be aware of items-list. We can do that by adding a `GroupContext` bindable property - which basically represents the parent list-view's `ItemsSource`.

When a switch is toggled, it iterates through the items-list to set the property as `false` on other items.

For example:

```
public class GroupedSwitch : CustomSwitch
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsGroupingEnabledProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "IsGroupingEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(GroupedSwitch),
            defaultValue: default(bool));

    public bool IsGroupingEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsGroupingEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsGroupingEnabledProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty GroupContextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
                    "GroupContext", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(GroupedSwitch),
                    defaultValue: default(IEnumerable));

    public IEnumerable GroupContext
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(GroupContextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GroupContextProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        if (propertyName != nameof(IsToggled))
            return;

        if (IsToggled != true || GroupContext == null)
            return;

        var currentItem = BindingContext as IToggableItem;
        if (currentItem == null)
            return;

        if (IsGroupingEnabled)
        {
            var groupList = GroupContext as IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, IToggableItem>>;
            var currentGroup = groupList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == currentItem.GroupName);
            if (currentGroup != null)
                foreach (var item in currentGroup)
                {
                    if (item != currentItem)
                        item.IsChecked = false;
                }
        }
        else
        {
            var simpleList = GroupContext as IEnumerable<IToggableItem>;
            if (simpleList != null)
                foreach (var item in simpleList)
                {
                    if (item != currentItem)
                        item.IsChecked = false;
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Third step would be bind `GroupContext` property to parent `ListView`'s items source. For example:

```
<ListView x:Name="ParentListView" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <local:GroupedSwitch 
                            IsToggled="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                            GroupContext="{Binding ItemsSource, Source={x:Reference ParentListView}}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Or,

```
<ListView x:Name="_parentList" IsGroupingEnabled="true" >
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Key}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <local:GroupedSwitch 
                            ToggledStateFromCode="{Binding IsSwitchOn}" 
                            IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                            GroupContext="{Binding ItemsSource, Source={x:Reference _parentList}}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[image]

**EDIT 1:** Updated code to add support for grouped list.

Comment: In the foreach is GroupContext not GroupedContext , right?
Can you go to the chat, please.

Comment: Yes it is `GroupContext`. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use triggers on each switch. Check this out:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xaml/xaml_triggers.htm

Comment: The problem is that the switch is created dynamically, can give me a example?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the switch is created dynamically"?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.